Low quality questions and answers from University assignments
Some of you will remember last year's visit from Lovely Professional University, where students were given an assignment to post on Stack Overflow with predictable quality results.
This year, it's the turn of "LNBTI" in Sri Lanka, who seem to be posting extensively in tags like data-structures, algorithms, binary-search-tree and similar.
Questions typically look like they're written from a template — for example, there was one in staging ground yesterday with

[Implementation Required]

left in the question.
Answers (which they're posting on fellow student's questions) largely look AI generated.
This is mostly a heads-up that it's going on. But for the sake of making this post an actual question:

is there anything we can usefully do to discourage this now that it's started (and that presumably there's a whole class that really needs to complete their homework assignment)?
is there anything we can do to discourage professors from setting this kind of assignment in future?


Examples
Many of these are/will probably be only visible to high-rep users at some point in the future. The list is by no means comprehensive. I've also only selected closed questions so at this stage there's no need to interact with them:
Questions: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Answers: old question that's attracted 3 answers, old question that's attracted 2 recent answers, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Bad universities will be bad. I don't think SO can fix them, short of making a black list/"hall of shame" post of some sort, warning against studying at certain universities.

I'm not sure if discouraging would be the right approach as it would be an easy way to get some users, but it just comes back to the overarching problem of making it clear what an acceptable post is and how to communicate/teach that

@Sayse I think you're unlikely to get an acceptable post if you ask a student to post something just to fulfil an assignment, and that something that might be acceptable starts to become unacceptable when 50 people try to do it at once.  I definitely don't want to discourage the students from the site in general (I'm sure this whole thing is frustrating for them too)

See Eternal September. I highly doubt there is anything SO can do except for IP bans and mass removal like last year. StackOverflow seems like a useful website, so a quick decision like "make a tudent join a useful website, give points for an attempt" is plausible regardless of any ToS or moderation policies. Any kind of communication will require professor's attention, and if they have any, they already know to not spam SO with questions.

Last year someone tried contacting the university. Not sure if that helped.

At least now we have the Staging Ground which should at least hold some of it off the main site and most/some of these will not graduate to real questions...

We have "Open letter to students." Maybe "Open letter to professors/universities" is worth writing as well.

How do we know that professors are setting this as an assignment? I read the linked question and its answer and it doesn't seem to be mentioned there. Am I missing something?

@DonaldDuck In the previous (LPU) version of this some of the students confirmed in comments. There are links to comments in that q&a. In this case I don't absolutely know - it might possibly be a spontaneous decision by a group of students, but that seems less likely.

@Sayse this site has no trouble getting new registrations. a sizable fraction of questions that I see, if not the majority, are from new accounts (which is natural because the older the account, the more someone has learned). this site has trouble attracting and keeping people that answer questions... and this site has trouble teaching new users to use the available resources (search, debugging, generally being self-sufficient in this age of information) instead of addressing the same questions to the same small pool of humans who are still willing to answer.

On the other hand: @Sayse "the overarching problem of making it clear what an acceptable post is and how to communicate/teach that" - we're collectively at least 10 years too late for that, and that problem is endemic to the entire world.

Just a note - I'm seeing a lot (as in, one-ish per day when usually I'd see zero) of Tower of Hanoi related questions quite suddenly. Could that be a symptom of this?

increases in topic-specific questions usually have someone causing them. it could be some youtuber. there are yt channels cranking out all kinds of content for the ad revenue. the audience can't assess the quality so it doesn't have to be great. they grow their audience by publishing on topics that their community asks for (give the people what they want). I watched videos of one youtuber who literally figured things out as he recorded the videos, and he uploaded them without editing. he had no understanding of what he did but but he was bold enough to "explain" it anyway.

@MT1 I think that's a great question and SO should provide an answer to it. lecturers/teachers should be given something that helps them explain (and themselves understand) SO in a way that doesn't misrepresent or harm the SO community. hell, if someone made a powerpoint presentation on this, that'd probably help a lot more than grumbling about the repeating/sustained floods or telling the lecturer to "stop it". I suspect we're only noticing specific floods but there's a constant background signal of new users being sent from lots of institutions. getting the multipliers to understand?

Prevention is impossible. Delete, delete, delete, delete as quickly as possible... is the best thing. Students won't be able to complete the idiotic assignment and the idiotic professors will change it. Close, downvote, and at -3, delete.

Several comments relating (directly or indirectly) to the geographic origin of these posts have been (or will be) removed. For the record: there are few enough instances of this happening that we could be talking about as few as 2 or 3 professors (spanning at least two countries) giving out these assignments. That's far too few to generalize to a regional/cultural issue. People from everywhere in the world post bad content on Stack Overflow. Please stick to discussing how to address the issue. Specific universities may be relevant, as they can be contacted, but entire regions are not.

Since 2014, I try not to answer pure homework questions anymore with a full answer. Often the question gets deleted almost instantly after answering. Some of the answers took some time and effort and some even contained some nice formulas. So the sad thing was not that much that the answer was removed, but I could not even check it back.

@Sayse: my experience is that a lot of them just copy the answer verbatim, hand that in... and delete the SO question to remove traces.

if they're voting on each others posts the accounts can be suspended for voting manipulation

Or similarly, if there is no centralized supervision and everyone and their mother can start up an university, that is also a problem. Ignoring it because we don't want to point fingers doesn't make the problem go away.

@WhatsThePoint in this case they seem fairly good at not voting on each other's accounts (or possibly few of the accounts have the reputation to upvote). So it's something to watch for, but not an issue here

FWIW I agree with @RyanM that the region is a distraction here - it's a big geographical region with a lot of universities, and only a very small number seem to set this kind of assignment (and even then, it's probably a specific professor who thinks it's a good idea).

I'll say one thing for patterns. When I was a student... if I didn't have to do something, I didn't do it. The less time spent on school work, the more time I could spend on playing video games. I don't think I was very unique in that respect although other people would have had other interests. But I had to do the work, I had no convenient buttons available to me to get other people or software algorithms to tell me what to do. Modern students do. I can't really blame them for hitting the buttons whether they were instructed to do so or not. I'd have done it too, I'm pretty sure of it.

I think exposure of the community and moderators to this practice in questions like this is a good start to getting this type practice under control. Whatever you call this "groupsourcing problems/answers by universities", once known, a clear policy like ChatGPT seems in order. This will make clear to both the university and students that coordinated posts for the purpose of school exercise, group answer or otherwise is off-topic and not allowed on SO. Then the community just has to get smart on identifying the posts and close them.

At the moment, it looks like the the flood of posts has finished (most likely just because the deadline for the assignment passed, but I don't know for sure)

@Gimby In high school or equivalent maybe. But with that attitude at an university you won't last long (not on a good one anyway) because normally there's nobody telling you what to do, you have to figure that out yourself by attending the classes. University students are assumed to be adults, as apposed to students in lower education that will be kids.

For posterity, would it be possible to post links or quoted/screenshotted examples of the offending questions+answers?

Sidenote: I've never used Teams, but this seems like a prime opportunity for somebody at SE (company) to reach out and offer these classes a free StackExchange For Teams thing. That way, the teachers can have moderator privileges, students don't have to deal with making a non-duplicate high quality question/answer and can just practice the format of a question, and SO users and mods don't have to deal with bad questions. And it's a win for SE (company) since those devs will potentially go to employers and say "in school we used SO Teams, that worked better than our current system".

INaturalist gets flooded with classroom assignments in a similar way. Here's their educator's guide, which seems like a good guide/comparison for Anerdw's open letter suggestion.

@Kaia I've linked a few examples. Many (especially the answers) will probably be inaccessible to you though.

In '09 I was in Uni - one lecturer gave us a short-form essay assignment, and said something akin to "if you want real feedback and feel like your essay is up to par, you could share it with [some mailing list]. I don't recommend everyone do this, and you won't receive any marks or kudos for doing it". At least 60% of the class (about 300 students) spammed that mailing list with their essays for about 2-3 weeks. This isn't a problem unique to SO, nor is it unique to given universities, or countries/regions. (con't)

Yes, Educators should be careful about unleashing students into the real world, but we're not going to stop them all, and complaining about it (even going so far as to make regional or racial inferences!) is not helping. What we should be doing is providing resources for Educators to help contribute in a positive fashion (or asking SE to do the same), and tweaking new-user tools and guidance for students.

@Robotnik Good universities do unleash the students in the real world, by making collaborations with real-world companies. We did something like first finishing a class in programming language x, then with the aid of the school poked real companies about small projects using language x. The company gets to know future potential recruits and a bit up free labour (although knowing that the work might be subpar). The students get to learn how programming is done in the real world and how working as a programmer will be. The school get good rep from the private sector. Everyone wins.

Mod note: Further comments about either 1) the geographic region of the two schools (from different countries) and people's general opinions of the quality of content posted from that region, or 2) whether certain universities have low-quality names, will be deleted without warning and may result in further action if continued. This is for a simple reason: it's completely unrelated to addressing the problem. Even assuming, for the sake of argument, that there is a statistically sound trend, what exactly is supposed to be done about that? Banning people from that region from posting?

You could write a comment asking the student to pass on a message to their prof asking them to read the main articles in https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking (what's on topic, how to ask, closed questions), and ask that they communicate those guidelines to their students.
Other than that, just downvote anything you decide you want to downvote. Vote to close anything that should be closed.

My feeling is that the message wouldn't be particularly effective coming from the students/they wouldn't really be willing to pass it on. However, I have to admit I haven't been commenting to let them know why what they're posting isn't helpful, so I don't know that for sure.

I would much rather, downvote the question, and vote to close the question resulting in the question not being answered.  Then attempt any sort of communication with any user who would submit such a low quality question. Sometimes a question is trash, and there is only one thing you can do with trash, and that's take it down to the curb as quickly as possible.

Presumably, the prof will see (at least screenshots of) the questions as part of marking the assignment. If the message is visible in the comments or answers, the prof should see it.

Assuming that the question isn't closed, sufficiently downvoted, and deleted before the professor gets a chance to see it or a screenshot is taken with the comment. Questions like this have a have a life expectancy of minutes in some of the busier tags.

@user7868 If the question is in a state sufficient for being handed in, there is no need for the professor to care about advisory comments that such questions are unsuitable.

@DavidW if the students are annoyed about the assignment - which, for any given assignment, some will always be - there will probably be some that gleefully forward the comments to the prof

People learning how to be devs.  Professor gives braindead assignment.  Community then decides to punish askers by downvoting their question and telling them they're doing it wrong. Welcome to being a dev on Stack Overflow I guess?  Seriously though, this screams a situation where StackOverflow staff should get into contact with the university and professor and explain why this isn't acceptable.
Punishing clueless kids probably just out of high school (or equivalent) doesn't feel like the right answer.

@AlbertEngelB fair point, if they ever come back to SO years in the future, they could potentially already be question banned because of something they were told to do by an authority figure, where not doing so could be putting their entire livelihood and education on the line. Even making new accounts would be considered ban evasion. This kind of situation might even be one unique enough which could justify allowing mods to lift post bans (though that seems VERY unlikely to ever be changed.)

@AlbertEngelB downvotes aren't a punishment mechanism. neither are close votes. people learning to be devs should also learn community etiquette in dev spaces.

@starball If students get an assignment then you can't blame them for doing. The best solution is to contact instructors and name and shame the universities involved. Can mods email the users on file? It would be good to have a standard email to send to students who seem to he executing an assignment.

@CorneliusRoemer nowhere did I blame the students for doing their assignment. it's strange to me that you immediately follow that accusation suggesting to shame an entire university. there's no need to shame people. if people want to fight this, fight bad education with good education (about how to ask a good question, to the students and their teachers).

@starball My point was that they won't learn etiquette if the assignment is bad, rewards/demand the wrong behavior. The assignments are the problem. To stop them, there needs to be awareness among teachers. To get awareness, shaming works: if teachers get in trouble for having gotten their university a bad rep that will spread among universities.

I think shaming is unnecessary / uncalled for, and in poor taste here

@CorneliusRoemer Moderators do indeed have the option to send a private message to a user, which also is sent to their email, if verified (which it would be for anyone asking a question).

Why is calling out (better word than shaming, I agree) bad here? It's bad behavior by a teacher that causes harm. If a teacher sent all the kids to the local coding club and they asked pointless questions but needed to take a selfie there to get marks, the local coding club would reach out to the teacher and ask them to stop. If the teacher doesn't care, they would tell their friends about it, talk to a newspaper. Imagine this coding club helps a lot of people who are polite, but now this mass of students who must take selfies and disrupt the club to get marks are destroying it for everyone.

shaming is less constructive. "you should feel bad". educating is "here's what we want/expect".

There are tools and people detecting AI and spam, both in the form of answers and questions. These can be effective albeit imperfect. This case seems like somewhere between the two. The most obvious thing to do is to downvote and close questions (as a human) and potentially do the same using AI or statistical approaches such as a Bayes classification that picks up on the "templates" somehow (yes, I know not how).
Approaches targeting individuals (well, preferably their questions), or worse those individuals' mentors, professors, and teachers can't scale and could appear to be a form of discrimination based on what hopefully originated as good intentions and not laziness from a student or teacher POV.
It is still fair to individually correct the behavior, but it can't be the sole method for such. Whatever the mechanism, some fair application of it should be considered. No one is at the same level of experience in their programming journey. That's a fact. Swift closure of a question may be the softest way out in most cases.
The really expensive option is to post Super Bowl level ads to stop the behavior! /joke
